# Jest Unexpected token 'export' when using d3

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, jestjs, vuejs3, ts-jest

I have read many of the questions similar to mine, but none seem to fix my issue. I am using Vue3, TypeScript, Jest, and D3 v7. When I try to `import * as d3 from "d3";` I get this error in my tests:

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":
  function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest)
  {export * from "d3-array";
```

This error also occurs when I import d3 as such
`import { BaseType, Selection, Transition, select } from "d3";`

I have tried updating my jest config's transformIgnorePatterns property to read but this doesn't work either:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!d3-(array))",
]
```

Could someone explain to me the piece I am missing here? Also below is my entire `jest.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    "**/src/**.ts", 
    "**/src/**/**.ts", 
    "!**/dist/**", 
    "!**/node_modules/**", 
    "!**/public/**"
  ],
  errorOnDeprecated: true,
  preset: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript",
  testMatch: ["**/*.spec.ts", "!**/node_modules/**"],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/dist/", "<rootDir>/node_modules/"],
  "modulePaths": [
    "<rootDir>"
  ],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!d3-(array))",
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.ts": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
  },
};
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A quick fix is to use the minified `d3` build, which is already transpiled. Either import the minified build directly:

```js
import * as d3 from 'd3/dist/d3.min'
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jest-use-transpiled-d3?file=jest.config.js)

Or use a Jest config to map `d3` to the minified build:

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^d3$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js',
  },
}
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jest-use-transpiled-d3-ecptpk?file=jest.config.js)

If that's not an option, you can configure Jest to transpile `d3` (and its dependencies that also require transpilation: `internmap`, `delaunator`, and `robust-predicates`):

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!d3|internmap|delaunator|robust-predicates)'
  ],
}
```

*Note: The transpilation adds considerable time to the test run.*

[demo 3](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jest-transpile-d3?file=jest.config.js)

Comment: For those using `CRA`: add this to `package.json`: `"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^d3$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/d3/dist/d3.min.js"
    }`

Comment: This worked great with Next.js using the SWC compiler (where configuring Jest to transpile the files with Babel isn't an option). Thanks!

Comment: For the latest nivo (0.83.0) I ran into this error for d3-colors. Here's my fix: `'d3-colors': '<rootDir>/node_modules/d3-colors/dist/d3-colors.min.js',`

Comment: @tony19 thank you so much for this answer; to add my 50 cents here: using moduleNameMapper if your module provides a minified version is much faster than transpiling with transformIgnorePatterns every time the tests run

Answer (score 0):

Following the tip from Tiep Phan's answer I added the following to my package.json file:

```
"jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/(?!d3|d3-array|internmap|delaunator|robust-predicates)"] },
```